# How do I loop through a list of report paramaters in Excel and automatically generate Report Server Reports as .PDF using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS report named "Customer Statement", and a large list of customer IDs and the relevant product a customer has bought. EG:

- C1222, Broadband
- C1223, Broadband
- C1224, Mobile
- C1225, Broadband
- C1226, Mobile

... (approx 10,000 records)

The report generates a customer statement and has two parameters, one for the type of report and one for the customer ID.

I need to save an individual .PDF of the exported report for each customer and place it into a folder, named as the customer ID. EG "C1222.pdf"

I've figured out half the problem, I can download the .PDF file directly from Report Server using an URL that looks something like this:

http://myreportserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fCustomer+Reports%2fCustomer+Statement&rs:Format=PDF&rs:ClearSession=true&Product=Broadband&CustomerID=C1222

Opening that link in a web browser automatically downloads the report as a .PDF file named "Customer Statement.pdf", with the correct parameters passed in.

What I need is to loop through my entire list and produce a file for each row, with the relevant parameters passed into the URL. The filename of the .PDF needs to be the customer ID from the list.

Ideally I want to do this in Excel with a VBA macro, but I'm open to using Powershell, SQL Server or even a Windows batch file if that would be easier.

EDIT:

I have SSRS Standard Edition, so a "Data-Driven Subscription" is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a bit of Googling and some trial and error, I have a working solution.

I placed my list into columns A and B of a worksheet named "Control" in Excel, and in column C I added a folder name, so that statements for each product type go to a different folder. I then run this VBA on the worksheet:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" _
(ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Sub DownloadStatements()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim Product As String
Dim CustomerID As String

'Loop down all records in Control sheet
For x = 2 To wb.Sheets("Control").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    'Set CustomerID to the relevant value
    CustomerID = wb.Sheets("Control").Range("A" & x).Value

    'Set ClientString to the relevant value
    Product = wb.Sheets("Control").Range("B" & x).Value

    'Set download filename to CustomerID + ".pdf"
    DownloadFile$ = CustomerID & ".pdf"

    'Set download URL as the report URL, passing in the Product and CustomerID as paramaters
    Url$ = "http://myreportserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fCustomer+Reports%2fCustomer+Statement&rs:Format=PDF&rs:ClearSession=true&CustomerID=" & CustomerID & "&Product=" & Product

    'Set local download location based on main output folder cell and output subfolder cell for the specific row
    LocalFilename$ = wb.Sheets("Control").Range("E2").Value & wb.Sheets("Control").Range("C" & x) & DownloadFile

    'Download the file (in a slightly cheaty way)
    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print "Some junk text " & URLDownloadToFile(0, Url, LocalFilename, 0, 0) = 0
    On Error GoTo 0

Next x

End Sub
```

All works perfectly, Excel will sit there and churn through the list creating the .PDF files, it's pretty quick and will be easy to automate further!